# What cases will cause a naive search of C++ code for primitive variables to fail?

Tags: c++, parsing

If I iterate through a C++ source file and simply look for variable types followed by correct C++ variable names, will there be circumstances that cause missing variables or false variables that would necessitate a proper parser to overcome?

A simple testcase correctly grabbed all the primitives but I would rather not invest too much time if there are many extraneous cases that I've not considered. So far, I'm simply looking for keywords, getting the next word and checking the name for validity.  I'm not using regexes except to check the validity of the variable name and I understand that regexes are not sufficient for parsing.

My program is written in Java. I did a Java target version of this program, and used JavaParser, which worked fine. I think ANTLR or some such is overkill for just finding primitive variables in a source.

Comment: `#define _(a) int _##a;` and `_(1) _(2) _(3)`

Comment: Template members and `auto` should be fun too.

Comment: The most vexing parse?  Even human readers sometimes have problems determing what is a variable, and what isn't.  Thus, `A * p;` declares a pointer if `A` is recognized as the name of a type; it does a multiplication and throws away the results otherwise.  Similarly `T<...` is the start of a template instantiation if `T` is a template; the `<` is less than otherwise.  In the end, you need to parse the C++ in all its glory, including what's in the included headers.

Comment: `if(tclass<int>::value < 0) {}` - how to you know tclass is a type and not part of the expression.

Comment: @Matt Thanks. In three words you managed to clear up any illusions I had about the simplicity or the task.

Comment: @James Thanks everyone.  Duly noted.  Find a lightweight parser to use live to code another day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try multiple variables declared on one line?

```
int i, *j, k[2];
```

What about function parameter declarations?

```
int func(int i, int j);
```

What about typedefs?

```
typedef int Integer;
Integer i;
```

Parsing C++ without a proper parser (and quite a complicated one) is hard.

Comment: Nice examples.  I was really hoping I could get away with a simple scanning of the source and grab the variables, but, as shown here, above, and below, I'm dreaming.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What about function parameters, multiple variables declared on the same line, the type and variable name on separate lines, etc?

Comment: Not to mention the additional context required to properly parse templates.

Answer (score 2):

The basic C++ declaration syntax is not a simple left-to-right `<type> <identifier>` syntax.

If this were C++'s syntax then, for example, declaring an array of ints would be done with the type `int[]` followed by an identifier:

```
int[] foo
```

Declaring a function would mean writing a function type such as `int()` followed by an identifier:

```
int() foo;
```

Instead C++'s syntax, inherited from C, is a style called "declarations mimic use"

```
<type_identifier> <expression>;
```

The expression in the declaration will look like a way you could use the declared entity, and that usage will produce the specified type.

Examples:

```
int i;      // now the expression i has the type int
int (ii);   // now the expression (ii) has the type int, and so ii has the same type
int j();    // now the expression j() has type int, and therefore j has a function type
int k[3];   // now the expression k[3] has type int, and therefore k has an array type
int (*l)(); // the expression (*l)() has type int, and therefore (*l) has a function type, therefore l has a pointer-to-function type.
```

And so on, with arbitrary complexity involving the array index operator, the function call operator, parens, the dereference operator, the bitwise-and operator, and probably some I don't remember. Additionally, const and volatile can be thrown in at various points.

To make matters worse, the declaration syntax can interact strangely with the syntax for initialzers. For example "The most vexing parse" is a situation where the parens from an initializer are confused with the parens involved in declaring a function type. Whether parens are part of the type expression or part of the initializer can depend on what the names used inside it happen to be:

```
struct bar {};
int baz() { return 1; }

int foo(bar());  // declaration of function (most vexing parse)
int foo2(baz()); // declaration of variable (initialized with baz())
```

And of course there are the issues mentioned by other people; typedefs/type aliases, macros, nested declarations, multiple declarations, etc.